# What is it like inside the sun?

Tags: space, hard-science, stars

In a freak chance of events, a spaceship is stranded in the sun, and the crew and ship is miraculously unharmed. After an attempted suicide, the crew realizes that through the same chance that put them in the sun, they can exit the ship and remain 100% safe while even outside of the ship. So after being in the sun for a while, they've noticed a few things that I don't have answers for, like:

Assuming that they will not die due to the heat, radiation, gases, etc,

- What is it like in the center of the sun?
- What does it smell like, if anything?
- What does it look like?
- Would they fall through the sun to the center, or is there a solid core they can stand on?
- How far away could you see a human in the sun?

Comment: This is a bit philosophical, but human senses have their limits based on the mechanics being used. What does 5000C feel like? it feels like nothing because the things doing the sensing are gone. What does the brightest light look like? It looks like nothing because you've been blinded. If you were invincible, your senses would just saturate and you would see white and feel the hottest pain you could feel (or you might feel no pain as I heard from someone who unknowingly rested their hand on a fresh weld).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this belongs on https://astronomy.stackexchange.com

Comment: *"How far away could you see a human in the sun?":* The mean free path of a photon inside the Sun is about 1 cm (less than half an inch). *"What is it like in the center of the sun?":* It is like absolutely amazing, like. *"What does it look like?":* It looks like the uncreated light illuminating the [luminous mysteries of the Rosary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosary), like. *"Would they fall through the sun to the center?":* Only if Archimedes's buoyancy principle is proven to have been fake news. *"What does it smell like?:* It smells like frankincense, and myrrh, like. Or something.

Comment: "*Assuming they will not die*" means that they have become godlike. Non-plasma matter cannot exist in that open fusion reactor.

Comment: It's not a world building question. It shows a decided lack of research into a question of fact. It asks for "hard science" in a situation that clearly requires some extraneous stuff. How do these bozos remain "100% safe" in the interior of the sun? Voting to close.

Comment: Just to remind everyone that the *backstory* is ***not*** what you should be worried about. Who cares why the astronauts aren't dead? That's not what we've been asked about and not a justifications to complain about the question unless the fact of the premise actually affects the fact of the answer (no matter what you might think, it doesn't in this case). However, Ceramic, @DKNguyen is very correct. There are limits to human senses and our experience stops at those limits. Those limits, for all practical purposes, are a better answer than the facts you're seeking.

Comment: @JBH the backstory is particularly important if you're asking us to explain what conditions inside a star are in relation to people who apparently won't instantly die and can **smell** stellar material.  The extreme lack of any effort in looking up e.g. the Sun on Wikipedia is pretty bad, but the backstory is immediately relevant in the sense that how they can exist at all in these conditions is problematic.

Comment: @StephenG that's really not true. In fact, if you apply that rationale to every question then about 90% of them should be closed for an unreasonable backstory. In fact, presuming the backstory produced an excellent observation about the limits of human senses that was thousands of times more valuable to the OP than, "they'd be dead, duh." Remember, this is worldbuilding, the OP defines the physics, not us. It's a bad habit to apply "real world" limitations to fiction w/o the OP's permission.

Comment: @JBH "the OP defines the physics" is *precisely* what the OP did **not** do.  They either need to outline the laws of their world's physics physics that lets them have people live inside a star or they need to provide a backstory that permits that in some way.  Without these rationales there is no answer possible but "they're dead, Jim".

Comment: @StephenG `The crew and ship [are] miraculously unharmed` The OP defined his/her expectations quite well and this kind of "take this initial setup without further explanation" assertion is ***common*** on this site. The OP is never obligated to prove to anybody that their premise is plausible or possible in the real world. Please stop arguing.

Comment: @JBH Presumably you didn't notice (or care anbout ?) the OP's **hard science** tag.  The OP **must** provide sufficient information to form an answer.  Requiring "hard science" and then providing no basis is just ridiculous.  And I'll argue my point as much as I bloody well like - don't tell people to shut up.

Comment: @StephenG [tag:hard-science] identifies the nature of the *answers,* not the *premise to the question.* No hard feelings, Stephen, but the backstory is the very last thing to judge when it comes to answering questions &mdash; and the entire premise of science is, "if we had the ability to withstand it, what would we find?" Also, the phrase "shut up" appears in none of my posts. The closest I came was "please stop arguing." I've said my piece. If you want the last word, it's all yours.

Answer (score 5):

/Assuming they will not die/

**They are already dead.**

The failure of the suicide should have been a clue and will be to your observant readers.  Your crew and its ship did die and their mortal remains are atoms in the solar furnace.  But their ghosts remain, and the ghosts do not know that is what they have become.

The sun as it appears to solar ghosts will probably not be the same as it would appear to us, or to a probe.  You can make it what you need to be according to rule of cool (if that applies to the interior of the sun).   And your crew might not be the only spirit inhabitants.  The perpetual fire of the sun is a fine place to banish undesirables, including, possibly, rebellious angels.

This could be a fine fiction.